# Converting string to date in ExtJs

Tags: date, extjs

I have a date in string format as follows-

```
"Fri Jul 11 2003 19:05:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

I want to check whether the date is a month old or not.
For this I am doing like this-

```
 var todaysDate= new Date();
 todaysDate.setDate(todaysDate.getDate() - 30);
 if(Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer("Fri Jul 11 2003 19:05:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", "D M d Y g:i:s") <= todaysDate)
 {

 }
```

It should return true but it is returning false. What I am doing wrong here.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing a renderer to a date, dateRenderer doesn't return a date, it returns a renderer. Renderers are used for example for grid cells, when you have a grid that has a record with a date and you want to display that date in a particular format you use a renderer to tell the grid cell how to format that date.

Check the docs about this: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-dateRenderer

Also I believe dateRenderer takes only one argument, you're passing two.

You can use regular Javascript for this:

```
var oldDate = new Date("Fri Jul 11 2003 19:05:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
var newDate = new Date()
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - 30);
if(oldDate <= newDate){
    doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Yes.. this is what I was exactly looking for.. so simple but could not striked... Thanks a ton !!!